# how do i align a list of strings to the right?

Tags: python, sorting, alignment

Is there a way for me to 'align' a list of strings to the right? I'm performing a counting sort here and I want sort my characters from the right.

For example, given a list of strings

eg. list = ['abc', 'a','qwerty', 'cd']

The length of the longest string in the list is 6 (qwerty),

```
list = ['abc', 'a','qwerty', 'cd']
biggest = max(list, key=len)
max = biggest - 1

list2= [] 
for col in range(-max, 0):
    for i in list:
       list2.append(i[abs(col)])
```

As my other strings are not the same length as qwerty, there will be an error, how do I 'align' all my strings to the right? so when I try to sort from the last alphabet, 'a' would be aligned with 'y' from 'qwerty' too.

```
     a
    cd
   abc
qwerty
```

And I would like to accomplish this **without padding**

Comment: If you looking to *print* them aligned to the right, you should say so.  Strings don't have any inherent "alignment".

Comment: oh no i just want to sort them aligned to the right sorry for being unclear! i don't need to print them

Answer (score 0):

```
list_1 = ['abc', 'a','qwerty', 'cd']
biggest = max(list, key=len)
biggest=len(biggest)
list_2=[]
//with padding
for i in list_1:
   list_2.append(' '*(biggest-len(i))+i)
//without padding
for i in list_1:
   list_2.append(f"{i:>{biggest}}")
```

I'd go with this approach

Comment: isn't this considered padding?

Comment: You can check this out then https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language , any reason not to use padding?

Comment: @SaiTeja: Because that was the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your whole list by length and use the [format mini language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) for output:

```
data = ['abc', 'a','qwerty', 'cd'] 


s = sorted(data, key=len)    # sorted copy of your list
maxlen = len(s[-1])          # longest is last element in sorted list

for l in s:
    print(f"{l:>{maxlen}}")  # not padded, just printed out right aligned
```

Output:

```
     a
    cd
   abc
qwerty
```

Comment: And if there are multiple strings of the same length?

Comment: @Scott the sorting is stable - they will occure in their original order if they got the same lenght. if you want to sort them by length, then alphabetically you need to change the key to : `sorted(data, key=lambda x: (len(x),x)` so they sort by length, then alphabetically - but that was not really part of the question? - or did I overlook something?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the question, this should be the solution:

```py
list_1 = ['aaaz', 'abc', 'a', 'qwerty', 'cd', "xxxxxxxxca"]


def my_sort(data):
    inverted = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[::-1])
    return inverted

max_len = max([len(s) for s in list_1])

list_2 = my_sort(list_1)
print(list_2)

>>> ['a', 'xxxxxxxxca', 'abc', 'cd', 'qwerty', 'aaaz']
```

I understand that the strings should be sorted alphabetically but from right to left.